# numpy - create array of index for the first element to its right that satisfies certain condition

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to do the following in numpy without incurring a for loop:

Suppose I have an array `x`, and for each element in `x`, I would like to find the index of the first element to its right that satisfies a certain condition. If there is no such element to its right, then return the length of the array.

For example, the array is
`x = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5]`
and the condition is the element is equal or greater than 4. In that case, the result should be
`y = [2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9]`
because the index of the first element equal or greater than 4 has value 5 and index 2, et al.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
def condition(a):
    return a>=4

def generate_array(arr, idx):
    if len(arr)==idx+1:
        return [len(arr)]

    n_arr = generate_array(arr, idx+1)
    if condition(arr[idx+1]):
        return [idx+1] + n_arr

    return [n_arr[0]] + n_arr
```

Then:

```
x = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5]
print(generate_array(x, 0))
[2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9]
```

Basically you can use the following facts

1. For any index `idx<len(arr)-1`, if `condition(idx+1)` is false, then the value will be the same as for idx+1. If `condition(idx+1)` is true, then the value will be idx+1
2. If `idx=len(arr)-1` then the value will be `len(arr)` since there aren't any value at the right of that idx

Comment: Thanks. I think although this does not involve a for loop, it is recursive hence it is still some kind of loop which would be very slow compared with native numpy functions.

Comment: Got it, I will try to think at something with just numpy. Although it will only be slow if you have a very very large array since it will be O(n) in time because it passes just once for each element. Do you have a max limit of the size of your array?

Comment: Thanks. The length of array is about one million so it can be finished in time, but there are lots of such arrays to be processed similarly, so still the faster the better.

Comment: I suggest you then use cython(https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html), it is basically python but running at C time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own answer:

```
x = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5]
index_condition = np.argwhere(x >= 4) # the selection criterion is elements >= 4
index_count = np.ediff1d(index_condition, to_begin=index_condition[0]) # get the count of each index in the final result as consecutive diff
result = np.repeat(index_condition, index_count) # repeat the index
# also need to pad the result to desired length but is easy
```